# Angular returning 401 unauthorized

Tags: angularjs, symfony

I have a page /home where I have a button. When I pressed the button I want to make a call to a login page. The controller symfony from that page return me a token. When I call that page in angular controller I can't authenticate, not talking to receive the token, returning me a

```
 Get (url) 401 unauthorized
```

when inspecting. If I go to login page I receive the token and the auth is successful. Why angular don't let me do it?

```
app.controller('home', function ($http, $scope, $window) {
$scope.go = function(){
    $http.get(
        '/login', { withCredentials: true }
    ).then(function (success) {
        $scope.token = success.data.Token;
        $window.localStorage.setItem('Token', token);
    });
};
});
```

The go function is activated when pressing the button from /home.

Comment: To `authorize` what are you checking or sending on login page ?

Comment: I have a password and a username, but that are going to my authenticator and in controller symfony it generates that token and it sends back. And that's what I'm trying to do. To take that token from /login, but when I make the call in angular it doesn't return me the token. I have some restriction also in security.yml

Comment: And only User_Authenticated can access the /login page, but I do not think it's because of it

Comment: You said `that are going to my authenticator and in controller symfony it generates that token`. In this code you are not sending any data to `/login` page ?

Comment: Well, when I press the button, it shows me to enter the username and the pass, and that thing , the authentication is made by symfony..and the symfony return the user token.. no?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you saying. Also in angular to send the username and pass? But i'm doing a get, not a post

Comment: What are you meaning with `authentication is made by symfony` ? Which page you are using to authentication ? If it is login page you need to send username&pass to login page. With get request or post request it is same you are requesting it differs only sending data.

Comment: I mean, that for example if I write in url ../login, it shows me the form, I authenticate and it goes to my authenticator in symfony, that checks if the user exists in system, and if does it sends me to controller and then returns me the generated token and that token I use in angular to put in every request. So i thought that when I make the call get from angular, when it said to enter the username and the pass, that credentials are going like above in authenticator, and if it's ok goes to controller and sends me the token. And then here in angular, retrieves the token and it puts in requests

Comment: OK, and then how to send the username and the pass? Because I don't have an actual form, that form it made me kerberos authentication.